# HttpClient.get doesn't get data from database realtime firebase in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

I am stayed debbugin and I think the error is in this part of code, my class DataService function cargarPersonas returns an Observable object but I don't know how learn this well and put the database data in the web:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        this.personaService.obtenerPersonas()
        .subscribe({
          complete: () => (personas: Persona[]) => {
              this.personas = personas;
              this.personaService.setPersonas(personas);   
          }
      });
      };
```

This is my database contains data:

[image]

This is my class Personas.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Persona } from '../persona.model';
import { PersonasService } from '../personas.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-personas',
  templateUrl: './personas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personas.component.css']
})
export class PersonasComponent implements OnInit{
  personas: Persona[] = [];

  constructor(
    private personaService: PersonasService,
    private router:Router
  ) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.personaService.obtenerPersonas()
    .subscribe({
      complete: () => (personas: Persona[]) => {
          this.personas = personas;
          this.personaService.setPersonas(personas);   
      }
  });
  };
  

  agregar(){
    this.router.navigate(['personas/agregar']);
  }
}
```

This is my class Data.services.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Persona } from './persona.model';

@Injectable()
export class DataServices{

   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}

    cargarPersonas(){
        return this.httpClient.get('https://listado-personas-4f1c0-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/datos.json');
    }

   //Guardar personas
   guardarPersonas(personas:Persona[]){
        this.httpClient.put('https://listado-personas-4f1c0-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/datos.json',personas)
        .subscribe({
            complete: () => { console.log("Guardar Personas: " + Response) }, // completeHandler
            error: () => { console.log("Error guardar personas: "+ Error) },    // errorHandler 
        });
   }
}
```

This is my class personas.services.ts:

```
import { LoggingService } from "./LogginService.service";
import { Persona } from "./persona.model";
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DataServices } from "./data.services";

@Injectable()
export class PersonasService{
    personas: Persona[] = [];


    saludar = new EventEmitter<number>();

    constructor(private logginService: LoggingService, private dataService:DataServices){}
    
    setPersonas(personas:Persona[]){
        this.personas = personas;
    }

    obtenerPersonas(){
        return this.dataService.cargarPersonas();
    }

    agregarPersona(persona: Persona){
        this.logginService.enviaMensajeAConsola("agregamos persona: " + persona.nombre);
        if(this.personas == null)
        {
            this.personas = [];
        }
        this.personas.push(persona);
        this.dataService.guardarPersonas(this.personas);
    }

    encontrarPersona(index:number){
        let persona: Persona = this.personas[index];
        return persona;
    }

    modificarPersona(index:number, persona:Persona){
        let persona1 = this.personas[index];
        persona1.nombre = persona.nombre;
        persona1.apellido = persona.apellido;
    }

    eliminarPersona(index:number){
        this.personas.splice(index,1);
    }
}
```

This is my personas.component.html:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <button style="cursor:pointer" (click)="agregar()">+</button>

</div>

<div class="box">
    <app-persona
      *ngFor="let personaElemento of personas; let i = index"
      [persona] = "personaElemento"
      [indice] = "i" 
    >
    </app-persona>
  </div>
  
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Edited: trying to Next:

Trying it with next does not execute the two statements inside the arrow function

[image]

Comment: There is quite some code and *a lot* of parts in your question. While it's always possible that somebody spots the answer and writes an answer, chances of that typically go up drastically if you isolate the problem to use fewer technologies. I.e. is there a way you can get this problem by just reading from Firebase through its REST API (as you do now) and logging the results? That'd rule out Angular as a potential source of problems, thus halving the problem space.

Comment: I don't know is there other way to get data from Firebase and show it in my screen, I'm only stay follow an Angular course and the teacher uses angular 13 and I use angular 15. I think thats is a problem of versions, i don't get any error in console. I only know that  the method "obtenerPersonas()" fails to reading data but not errors show me.

Comment: Have you tried with `next` instead of `complete`? The `complete` observer does not return a value, only the `next` observer will return a value. See [Observer in RxJS documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/Observer).

Comment: @Lars 
I have edited the question answering you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, instead of the `complete` observer use the `next` observer. The `next` [observer returns the values](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/Observer), where the `completed` observer only indicates that the observable has completed. Secondly there are currently two functions, but the first does not have any parameters, so you are not receiving the value.

Changing the subscription to `next` and removing the first arrow function, resolves your problems.

```js
this.personaService.obtenerPersonas().subscribe({
  next: (personas: Persona[]) => {
  // use your personas data
}
```

[Here is a simple Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zja1lj?file=src/app/app.component.ts) which tries to imitate your structure.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve my question with this code:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.personaService.obtenerPersonas()
    .subscribe({
      next: (item) => { 
          console.log("Guardar Personas: " + item); 
          this.personas = item as Persona[];
          this.personaService.setPersonas(this.personas);  
      },
      error: () => { console.log("Error guardar personas: "+ Error) }, 
      complete: () => { console.log("Guardar Personas se ha completado")}   // errorHandler 
    });
  };
```